# Disappear debug cursor in codeblock

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

when I clicked red start button ( debug / continue button), Yellow debug cursor appeared and stoped before breakpoint.
But suddenly, these days when I started debug, yellow cursor didn't appear and didn't stop before breakpoint, just worked like build and run.
what can I do to get yellow cursor again?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC6Dv.png)

Comment: could you show us the toolchain configuration ?

Comment: I'm sorry to reply late!! and thank you for your comment! I added a image